# What does the phrase "其空有名头" mean?

Tags: meaning

I've heard this phrase;

> 其空有名头~

But I'm looking for some clarification as to what it means?
I've tried to break it down and parse it myself but I come up with something that seems quite unnatural.

If I had to guess, I think it could mean something like "in name only" ? Or "just as a formality".

Answer (score 1):

其 is a possesive pronoun. The subject in the phrase is not mentioned.

空有= have only; 名头= title/name

**空有名头** means "**in name only**" (either 'in a position that have no real power' or 'enjoy a reputation that is undeserved')

“其空有名头” = "his/her 'in name only'"

We need more context to decide which meaning we are talking about.

Are you sure it wasn't '空有其名?' because  '空有其名'(only has it's name/ in name only) is a common phrase along with '虛有其表' (only has it's appearance/ in appearance only)

Answer (score 0):

It means someone only has a title, but doesn't have the actual power. 
Or, someone is known to be good at something, but actually is not.

Answer (score 0):

其 a personal pronoun. Here refers to 他/它.

空 here can be interpreted as 'merely'

有 here is the verb in the sentence, meaning 'have'

名头 roughly means 'one's fame or one's title'

Overall, 其空有名头 means 'He（ or it ） merely has his fame/title'. Implies one doesn't have the ability as one is known as, or is not as capable as one is thought.

As for parsing it： 其（subject） 空(adverb modifying 有) 有(verb) 名头(object).

Answer (score 0):

I get: 浪得虚名： have an unearned reputation for 空有名头

I parse 其空有名头 as

其 she/he/it/they
空 for no reason
有 have
名头 reputation/(good) name